Redis and spring data very slow
I have configured spring-data-redis and redis as follows. But its very slow at the moment when fetching data, a size of data thats simple pojos of 1K, take 2+ seconds
config
 @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Instant> redisTemplate(final RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Instant> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return template;
    }

my pojo
@Data
@Builder
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@RedisHash("cars")
public class Car {


    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private String plate;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate made;
    @JsonIgnore
    @TimeToLive
    Long ttl;

}

Standard SPring data jpa interface repository, im saving which isnt too bad,But the retrieval is taking too long. Can i make it faster?
I have tried using GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer which has helped a little, is there any other way
